gcc not installing properly on wsl-2
I want to compile my c programs on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running on WSL-2.  Try as I might, I keep getting the following error:
> myFile1.c:1:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
> 1 | #include <stdio.h>
>       |          ^~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.

It seems that the standard gcc header files were never installed in /usr/include
Does anyone have ideas on how I can trouble shoot this? Thanks!
What I tried before:
I initially ran...
$ sudo apt install gcc
then...
$ sudo apt install gcc --fix-missing
then...
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
$ sudo apt autoremove -y
$ sudo apt-get install gcc -y
However, none of this fixed the problem.  When I run gcc myFile.c -o myProgram.exe && ./myProgram I get the same error as above.

You need to install glibc or other libc implementation. I recommend installing the build-essential package.
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential

The build-essential package is designed to include software necessary to build Debian packages, which probably isn't what you need -- but includes all the packages necessary to build C code, including gcc and glibc.
Minimally, you can install the libc6-dev package.

thanks for the suggestions.  However, when running sudo apt upgrade many items were not fetched because [IP: 91.189.91.83 80] was not found. When running sudo apt install build-essential it failed because [IP: 185.125.190.39 80] was not found.  FYI, my gcc version is 11.4.0  and my Ubuntu release is 22.04.3.  What do I do from here?

Change your repo: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

You can manually update your /etc/apt/sources.list. Please google ubuntu sources.list.

example: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/repogen/

Okay, here is what I did.

I got rid of all my gcc stuff (probably not nessessary):
sudo apt remove gcc

I made a backup of my /etc/apt/sources.list:
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.backup

Found a mirror site to get my gcc files by going to
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine
Followed the link "official mirror list" on that page
Found a mirror for the United States (I used Pilot Fiber)

Grabbed the URL from the mirror site
https://mirror.pilotfiber.com/ubuntu/

Edited my sources.list to include the mirror site
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
then commented out top repository and added the mirror-site repository
[COMMENTED OUT -->] #deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main
restricted
[ADDED -->] deb https://mirror.pilotfiber.com/ubuntu/ jammy main
FYI, jammy is the codename for my Ubuntu distribution (you can find yours
via the command line with lsb_release -a)

Updated my apt source list
sudo apt update

Used apt to install "build-essential" which includes the gcc compiler
sudo apt install build-essential

Checked for gcc
gcc -version
output: gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 ...

Successfully compiled and ran some test programs



best wishes to you and happy hacking...
